# How to count in sql using three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got three tables and want I want to do is to count how many useage I've got from each order.

Users:

```
IDs    UserID
1     25
2     32
```

Orders:

```
ID     StartDate     StopDate     Count        UserID
1      01.01.2013    10.01.2013   10           25
2      13.01.2013    16.01.2013   4            25
3      10.01.2013    23.01.2013   13           32
4      25.01.2013    26.01.2013   2            32
```

Usage:

```
Date           IDs
01.01.2013     1
02.01.2013     1
03.01.2013     1
13.01.2013     1
21.01.2013     1
11.01.2013     2
26.01.2013     2
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
OrderID      Counter  IDs(or UserID)       
1            3        1(or 25)     
2            1        1(or 25)
3            1        2(or 32)
4            1        2(or 32)
```

Unforutnatly, I can't edit tables - is it possible in SQL query?

Comment: Your expected output is clear except for `IDs(or UserID)`

Comment: Could you give me an adivce, please?

Comment: Yes: Clarify that column :) The counter is clear, as I said before. The issue is that I don't understand why the column says `OR`. Is it the `ID` or the `UserID` what you're looking for? The latter would be easier because it would save a join with the user table as you can get the `userID` from the `Orders` table. Also, are those `date`s or strings? Huge difference! (MySQL displays dates as `YYYY-MM-DD`)

Comment: @Mat, Do you really expect concatenated result as IDs(or UserID) both or either of them?

Comment: In usage and order table i've got dates not string - my fault, sorry (in Poland DD.MM.YYYY format is the most common). I expect IDs on output...

Comment: @Mat Whoops. I've just realized I don't see why `orderId = 2` has a counter of `1` while it should be `0`

Comment: Why it should be 0? I've got usage on 13.01, while the order was also on 13.01

Comment: Negative. The usage for `13.01` is for order `1`. I'm asking for order with id `2`. I'm assuming the field `IDs` in the `Usage` table is a foreign key to the `orders` table... right?

Comment: Unfortunatly not, it's from Users table.

Comment: @Mat Store your dates in an ISO standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT o.id, COUNT(usg.ids) counter, u.userID FROM users u
JOIN orders o ON u.userId = o.userId
LEFT JOIN usage1 usg
ON u.ids = usg.Ids AND usg.date BETWEEN o.startDate AND o.stopDate
GROUP BY o.id, u.userID
```

Output:

```
| ID | COUNTER | USERID |
|----|---------|--------|
|  1 |       3 |     25 |
|  2 |       1 |     25 |
|  3 |       1 |     32 |
|  4 |       1 |     32 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b481/1).

You can change `u.userID` in the select and group by clauses for `u.IDS` if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to test it now, so I will give feedback in few minutes.